# caching effects due to SO_BINDTODEVICE in setsockopt

Tags: c, linux, sockets, networking, setsockopt

by `SO_BINDTODEVICE` socket option we could **set the socket to one of the network interface**  , also if ***we use two NIC cards*** and if we want to set the socket to one of the NIC card the SO_BINDTODEVICE will help .

if we set the socket to **eth1** in the `setsockopt` through `SO_BINDTODEVICE` then the socket will send and receive all the packet through eth1 interface .

This is what so far my understandings on the SO_BINDTODEVICE option , and there is a statement about SO_BINDTODEVICE and  that is

> You *can* call BINDTODEVICE more than once for a socket to change the
>   interface it's  bound to, but results may be unpredictable because of
>   caching effects in the kernel.

What does the that means , i could not understand , is this about cache table(routing table) of LAN network which connected , explanation please

Comment: It is about 'caching effects in the kernel', and nothing more specific than that.

Comment: And in practice it means "you probably shouldn't call it twice on the same socket"

Comment: May be the real cause is bit too much to put in the statement. I can think about the SMP case where for each interface there are multiple queues allocated for connection handling tied to a particular CPU. This makes use of cache locality (cached networking structures) per CPU efficiently. If you change the interface multiple times its gonna affect somewhere considering the complexity.  Between, I am just putting down my words, may not be relevant at all.